# Looking for a possible one call for multiple checks in arraylist

Tags: java

Does someone know if there is an existing method that I can use to do all the check I am doing with my 2 lists below? I was think of using CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection but then my size check can not be taken into account.

```
public booblean StringArrayListEqual(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {          
    // both are empty or null they are equal
            if ((list1 == null || list1.size() == 0) && (list2 == null || list2.size() == 0)) {
                return true;
            }
            // One is empty, but the other was not, then they are not equal!
            if ((list1 == null || list1.size() == 0) || (list2 == null || list2.size() == 0)) {
                return false;
            }
            // check size
            if (list1.size() != list2.size()) {
                return false;
            }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd rewrite your function like this:

```
final int s1 = list1 != null ? list1.size() : 0;
final int s2 = list2 != null ? list2.size() : 0;
return s1 == s2;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a single method call but it is a cleaner way.
You could use  `org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.isEmpty()` method from Apache common collections :

```
boolean isList1Empty = CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list1);
boolean isList2Empty = CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list2);

if (isList1Empty && isList2Empty) {
    return true;
}
// One is empty, but the other was not, then they are not equal!
else if (isList1Empty || isList2Empty)
    return false;
}
// check size
else if (list1.size() != list2.size()) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: Thank you all. I would like to know if I there is an existing method that I can use to compare the size of my 2 lists. The reason why I am asking that is just because these checks slow down my app

Comment: You are welcome. These checks are really cheap. These should not slow down your application but if you perform them thousand times by second. You should concentrate your improvement on clean and readable code and monitor your application with tools as jvisualvm to understand the slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

to clarify:

- null check can be done as:

  list == null

- list emptiness:

```
`list.isEmpty()`
```

(list.size will work too, but the API has an elegant method returning a boolean with exactly the result you need..)

so you can combine those boolean returned values and make the 4 possible combinations that your app may require...